# How to use the modified bootstrap in Flat-UI in a Meteor app?

Tags: meteor

I am using bootstrap in Meteor and found that there is a modified flat design here: http://designmodo.com/demo/flat-ui/.  Among the files seems to be a modified set of Bootstrap files.  Is it possible to somehow use those css and js files to override the default bootstrap files to get the Flat-UI in a meter app?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's quite simple:

unzip the contents of the flat-ui-master.zip from the flatui site, then follow these steps:

1. create these folders in your app root: /client/stylesheets
2. copy the contents of the .zip into /stylesheets
3. remove the index.html and README.md files as they might cause your app to crash, and are not needed

meteor automatically takes care of the rest.

Comment: it took a little bit of folder placement to get this to work, but this method worked for me, generally.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Although manually insert files works, I'm using meteor package [jss:flat-ui](https://atmospherejs.com/jss/flat-ui)

```
meteor add jss:flat-ui
```

it will automatically add flat-ui and twbs:bootstrap.

Note that, it might be better to remove any bootstrap package before installing this, I've been in a project that has mizzao:bootstrap installed and the login ui not working, so I remove mizzao:bootstrap and reinstalled flat-ui to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever css you want to, Meteor don't care.

I wouldn't add the bootstrap meteor package though, I'd just download the css files you want and place them in your project. That way you know exactly what files are used and can easily make changes.

Here's some info on how to structure your app: https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I would still like to use Bootstrap functionality, like navbars, dropdowns, and other components though.  If I just add the css files from the Flat-UI package, could I still use those components as is?

Comment: As this ain't Meteor specific, you can add whatever files you'd like. I don't know how the flat-package works together with Twitter Bootstrap, but there's nothing in Meteor that will prevent them from working together.

Answer (score 0):

I created a shell script to generate a custom bootstrap Meteor package from either a precompiled distribution, or from your own clone of the Bootstrap Git repository.
You can find it here, along with usage information: https://github.com/wojas/meteor-package-bootstrap

Just unpack the ZIP file containing the files and run this command from inside the theme folder:

```
/path/to/meteor-package-bootstrap.sh $your_meteor_project/packages/bootstrap
```